# How can i change a style in tailwind according to an useState change?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, tailwind-css

I have a div that i want its width to switch between 260px and 85px as i click on a button (that will trigger an useState), but i tried a few different ways and none is giving me the result im looking for.
Heres my code (without trying to apply the usestate in the navs classname):

```
export function Menu(){
const [expanded, setExpanded]= useState(true);
return(
    <aside className="h-screen">
        <nav className= {'h-full flex flex-col bg-sidebar w-[260px]'}>
            <div>
                <button onClick={()=>setExpanded((curr)=> !curr)}>
                <img src="/Menu.png" alt="menuLogo" className="absolute top-4 ml-[23px]"/>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the `nav` Tailwind class dependent on the `expanded` state:

```html
<nav className={'h-full flex flex-col bg-sidebar ' + (expanded ? 'w-[260px]' : 'w-[85px]')}>
    <div>
        <button onClick={()=>setExpanded((curr)=> !curr)}>
            <img src="/Menu.png" alt="menuLogo" className="absolute top-4 ml-[23px]"/>
        </button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use Javascript template literals to achieve your goal.

Ideally, this is what you will have to do:

```
export function Menu(){
const [expanded, setExpanded]= useState(true);
return(
    <aside className="h-screen">
        <nav className= {`h-full flex flex-col bg-sidebar transition-all duration-500 ${expanded ? 'w-[260px]' : 'w-[85px]'}`}>
            <div>
                <button onClick={()=>setExpanded((curr)=> !curr)}>
                <img src="/Menu.png" alt="menuLogo" className="absolute top-4 ml-[23px]"/>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </aside>
)}
```

I also added a Tailwind's transition utilities for a smooth transition both ways. Hope this helps :)